# Bold Italic Number

Tags: math-mode, fonts

How to show the number 1 in bold italics math font? I tried using `\bm{1}` but the looks seems ain't any different from `\bf{1}`.

Comment: note that `\bf` is not defined by default but if used the syntax would be `{\bf 1}` not `\bf{1}`  `\bm{\mathit{1}}` probably does what you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`\bm` will make it bold, but you want `\mathit` to make it italic.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{bm}

\begin{document}

$1 + \mathit{1} + \mathbf{1} + \bm{\mathit{1}} $
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted. Thank you man.